# Gulp produces empty css file (compilation sass to css)

Tags: css, sass, compilation, gulp

I want to compile my sass file to css but it doesn't work, although it has worked recently (i did the same things and all was normally). My CSS file is just empty.

Here is the task

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/sass/*.sass')
   .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});
```

I've reinstalled packages and node js but it didn't help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0eMN.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, can you please post the gulp tasks as formatted code instead of images?

Comment: Sorry I meant in original question, not as a comment.

Comment: Do you mean that the dist/css _directory_ is empty?

Comment: No, it compiles. There is style.css but it's empty while style.sass has some code.

Comment: And can you show a minimal .sass file that compiles to an empty .css file too.

Comment: If you change your style.sass to style.scss does that work, with  return gulp.src('src/sass/*.scss')?  Do you need to use sass indented syntax files?  If not, try .scss files iinstead.

Comment: Omg thank you, there was just an mistake in my sass code. i've written colon (like background-color: $header-color and it worked). My bad. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There was just a mistake in my sass code. i've written colon (like background-color: $header-color and it worked). My bad.